# How to embed version / copyright / manufacturer information in a shared library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, version

Dynamic libraries on Windows (.dll) support a predefined format for storing meta data such as version number, copyright, manufacturer, etc. directly within the library itself. Retrieving that information is as simple as viewing the properties of the library.

Now, I'm looking for a way to do something similar on Linux. Can anyone tell me how I can embed such meta data directly within a shared library (.so) and point me how to extract that information with standard tools on Linux?

Is there a predefined way to do so at all?

While researching that topic I came across the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314800) on SO. However, that question dates back to 2010 and the accepted answer seems to no longer be recommended.

So, how is this done in 2019?

Comment: Nothing has changed in 2019. The only "official" field is version. You might be able to use a custom section for copyright and manufacturer. And if you were not aware, the version information is perverted under Linux. It does not follow *Major-Minor-Revision*. See [Updating library version information](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Updating-version-info.html) in the libtool manual.

Comment: Alright, your comment is already helpful, thanks for it.